# JS password strength checker

Tags: javascript, html

Im learing RegExp for JS and I'm trying to create a script that will say that the password is either weak of will let it go through
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="password" id="pw" />
            <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="click me!" />
        </form>
        
        <div id="info"></div>

        <script src="script.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: wheat;
}

input#pw {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input#myBtn {
    width: 75px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 54%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 47%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
    animation: pulse 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }

    25% {
        transform: scale(1);
        color: red;
    }

    75% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(0.75);
    }
}
```

```
window.onload = function(){
    var info = document.getElementById("info");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myForm").myBtn;

    btn.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pw = document.getElementById("myForm").pw.value;
        var regExpPattern = /(?=.*[0-9]) (?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[A-Z]).{5,}/;
        
        if (regExpPattern.test(pw))
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        else
            info.innerHTML="password weak";
    };
};
```

So as you can see I'm trying to use RegExp to see if the password has uppercase, lower-case letter and a number. It should also make sure that you're password is at least 5 symbomls long.

Whenever you give it a try and your password is incorect it does say "password weak" but when you try to type 5 letter, one number, on uppercase and lower-case letters it doesn't do anything.

Please help, I don't know what to do :D can somebody explained it to me as well please <3

Comment: Why not just loop through the characters using JavaScript?. RegEx is not very suitable for the task at hand and the JavaScript code will be must easier to read.

Comment: Well, as I've said I'm just trying to learn how it works so I can read the code in the future if somebody would use it :)

Comment: Consider not doing this at all.  https://www.netsec.news/ncsc-recommends-against-arbitrary-password-complexity-requirements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion: split your validation criteria up and then check each one individually. You can put the pattern and the corresponding issue text into an object for each validation to make it easier to tell the user what the problems were if validation failed.

```
let validations = [
    { pattern: /[a-z]/, issue: 'Must include lowercase letters.' },
    { pattern: /[A-Z]/, issue: 'Must include uppercase letters.' },
    { pattern: /[0-9]/, issue: 'Must include numbers.' },
    { pattern: /.{5,}/, issue: 'Must be at least 5 characters long.' }
];
let pwd = document.getElementById("myForm").pw.value;
let validationIssues = validations.filter(validation => {
    return !pwd?.match?.(validation.pattern);
}).map(validation => validation.issue);
if (validationIssues.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Your password was too weak for the following reasons: ${validationIssues.join('\n')}`);
}
```

Comment: You should not use `filter()` here. Use `every()` instead, which returns `true` if all conditions match and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @Mushroomator That's a good thought, but in this case I'm using filter so that we know, specifically, which ones failed. That way we can report to the user what the issues were. Using every() would be an all or nothing proposition and wouldn't allow us to know which ones failed, right?

Comment: Yes you're right, didn't see you were giving a reason. Perfectly reasonable in that case :)